# When retrieving the keys and values from a dictionary in c# are they guaranteed to share the same indexing?

Tags: c#

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();

dict.Add("one",1);
dict.Add("two",2);
dict.Add("three",3);
dict.Add("four",4);

List<string> keys = dict.Keys.ToList();
List<int> values = dict.Values.ToList();
```

From the code above if the list of keys looked like this 
`{ "two" , "four" , "three" , "one"}` would the list of values always look like this `{ 2 , 4 , 3 , 1}`

Comment: [The order in which the items are returned is undefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). EDIT: See Lee's answer.

Comment: FYI, [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, so you can iterate over it with the keys and values together in a single loop. I'm curious; why are you splitting them out into separate lists and concerned about the indexing? That seems inherently "dangerous" since they are no longer bound to each other and any change in one list could introduce a hard-to-find bug (depending on what you're doing).

Comment: I created an array from the values which I used to find the similarity with other arrays that I created using the same indexing from the keys, the other arrays are created immediately after, then the data from the dictionary isn't reused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netframework-4.8):

> The order of the values in the Dictionary.ValueCollection
>   is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the
>   Dictionary.KeyCollection returned by the Keys property.

Comment: Ah, missed that documentation part. Upvote for you!

Comment: I guess with the atomicity / concurrency caveat that Keys and Values must be copied or enumerated without any changes in between obtaining the `Keys` and `Values`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually dictionaries maintain their order in the same order as the associated keys.